# his is my output after running sudo apt-get update. help me

Tags: apt, updates

```
E: The repository 'https://packages.sury.org/php jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: A quick look at details from your *pasted* info & I can quickly see the resource you are trying to use is for Debian and not Ubuntu releases. It has no support for any Ubuntu release; let alone 22.04 or *jammy* you appear to be using.  FYI:  *To look at what you pasted; I just highlight part of your paste & open in a new tab & I can explore quickly what the repository provides support for... ie. nothing other than what you provided is required to get to* https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/

Comment: @guiverc jammy is Ubuntu, not Debian. Am I missing something?

Comment: @moo  the resource the OP is attempting to use (ie. https://packages.sury.org/php) is for Debian systems only, providing support for *stable* **bookworm**, *old-stable* **bullseye** & *old-old-stable* **buster** ONLY; ie. no support for any Ubuntu product, but only support for Debian *supported* releases...  (no support for *jammy* which is 22.04)... if you click the link I provided (*prior comment*) OR just follow what the OP posted (*what I opened from question*) you'll end at the reason for my comments